# Create a menu tree using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an requirement to create a tree structure menu from a . separated string array.

My out put should be like following

```
        A
            A1
                A2
                A3
            B1
            B2
        B
            B1
                B2
                B3
                    B4
        C
            C1
                C2
        C4
```

I am trying to implement that with the following script

```
        <script>
            function fnAppend(param) {
                var  cWin=window.open("","Categories","width=600,height=800,scrollbars=yes");
                var array = ['A.A1.A2', 'A.A1.A3', 'A.B1.B2','C.C1.C2','B.B1.B2','B.B1.B3.B4','C4'],
                tree = [],
                levels = [tree],
                last = [];

                array.forEach(s => {
                    var temp = s.split('.');
                    temp.forEach((name, i) => {
                        if (last[i] === name) return;        
                        levels[i].push({ name, children: levels[i + 1] = [] });
                    });
                    last = temp;
                });

                function traverse(arr) {
                    for (const branch of arr) {
                        console.log('Mother:', branch.name);
                        var ul=document.createElement('ul');
                        var li=document.createElement('li');
                        li.innerHTML="<a href=''>"+branch.name+"</a>";
                        ul.appendChild(li);
                        if (Array.isArray(branch.children) && branch.children.length > 0) {
                            console.log('Children:', branch.children.map(i => i.name).join(', '));
                            traverse(branch.children);
                        }
                    }
                    var list = document.createElement('div');
                    list.appendChild(ul);
                    try {
                        cWin.document.body.appendChild(list);
                    } catch (err) {
                        if (list.outerHTML) {
                            cWin.document.body.innerHTML = list.outerHTML;
                        } else {
                            console.log(err.name);
                        }
                    }
                }
                traverse(tree);
            }
        </script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <ul id="mylist">

            </ul>
            <input type="button" value="Append child" onclick="fnAppend('test')" />
        </body>
```

Using above script I am getting the following output

```
A3
B2
B1
C2
C1
B4
B3
B1
C4
```

Please help me to format the output.
Many thanks in advance.

Regards,
Pankaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create tree and build a nested list with items.

```js
function buildList(tree, target) {
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    tree.forEach(node => {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(node.name));
        node.children.length && buildList(node.children, li);
        ul.appendChild(li);
    });
    target.appendChild(ul);
}


var array = ['A.A1.A2', 'A.A1.A3', 'A.B1.B2','C.C1.C2','B.B1.B2','B.B1.B3.B4','C4'],
    tree = [];

array.forEach(s => s.split('.').reduce((t, name) => {
    var temp = t.find(o => o.name === name);
    if (!temp) {
        t.push(temp = { name, children: [] });
    }
    return temp.children;
}, tree));

console.log(tree);

buildList(tree, document.body);
```

A different approach wich works only if pop ups are allowed.

```js
function open() {
    var cWin = window.open("", "Categories", "width=600,height=800,scrollbars=yes");

    cWin.document.write(buildList(tree).outerHTML);
}

function buildList(tree) {
    if (!tree.length) return;
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    tree.forEach(node => {
        var li = document.createElement('li'),
            children = buildList(node.children);
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(node.name));
        if (children) li.appendChild(children);
        ul.appendChild(li);
    });
    return ul;
}


var array = ['A.A1.A2', 'A.A1.A3', 'A.B1.B2','C.C1.C2','B.B1.B2','B.B1.B3.B4','C4'],
    tree = [];

array.forEach(s => s.split('.').reduce((t, name) => {
    var temp = t.find(o => o.name === name);
    if (!temp) {
        t.push(temp = { name, children: [] });
    }
    return temp.children;
}, tree));

console.log(tree);
```

```html
<button onclick="open()">popup</button>
```

Comment: Hi Nina, Thank you very much for your response.It will working fine but I have another question, if I need to open the tree in a new window, how to do that?

Comment: @PankajKarmakar, please try the last one outside of stack snippets.

Comment: Its working but if you check my code there I have to open the new window with menu once I have click on a button.

Comment: Hi Nina,Is there any way to append a class to next li of each parant and also need to add <a> to all the end child li of every parent.

Comment: you could add this in the `forEach` callback.

Comment: I am able to add class, Now I have to just add <a> for href purpose to all the end children, can you please help me @Nina

Comment: the end is the part of `if (children) li.appendChild(children);`, where you could add an `else` part, generate a tag for `a` and append this element to `li`.

Comment: else{
  var ref = document.createElement('a');
  ref.href = "javascript:window.close();";
  ref.innerHTML = node.name;
  ref.id = node.name;
  li.appendChild(ref);
  li.className='schild';
 }

Comment: But I am getting like OtherOther double out put

Comment: I will generating following out put                                                                               
<li class="schild" style="list-style-type: none;">Temperature<a href="javascript:window.close();" id="Temperature">Temperature</a></li>    
where as I need like following                                                                                      <li class="schild" style="list-style-type: none;"><a href="javascript:window.close();" id="Temperature">Temperature</a></li>

Comment: it should be something more like this: `tree.forEach(node => {
    var li = document.createElement('li'),
     children = buildList(node.children);
    if (children) {
     li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(node.name));
     li.appendChild(children);
    } else {
     var ref = document.createElement('a');
     ref.href = "javascript:window.close();";
     ref.appendChild(document.createTextNode(node.name));
     ref.id = node.name;
     li.appendChild(ref);
     li.className = 'schild';
    }
    ul.appendChild(li);
   });`

Comment: Thank You Very much @Nina, It's working now.Really appreciate your effort.

Comment: Hi @Nina,If I have an array like following 
var array = [{id : '001',name : 'A.A1.A2'}, {id : '002',name : 'A.A1.A3'}, {id:'003',name : 'A.B1.B2'},{id : '004',name : 'C.C1.C2'},{id : '005',name : 'B.B1.B2'},{id : '006',name : 'B.B1.B3.B4'},{id : '007',name : 'C4'}]

want to include id, how to write following loop 
array.forEach(s => s.name.split('.').reduce((t, name) => {
  console.log(t);
  var temp = t.find(o => o.name === name);
  if (!temp) {
   t.push(temp = { name, children: []});
  }
  return temp.children;
 }, tree));

Comment: Basically I need id along with the name.

Comment: then take the `id` out of the object. btw, in comments it's not the right place to extend question.

Comment: Apologize for that, I will open a new question.